# Excel Vba-fill data infront of each cell

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

I created a macro that scrap data from website **("Hope this code helps alot of viewers ")** and then print it into sheet `Feuil1`, the code works perfectly but the only issue that always I Have a problems with filling Table :'(

Which mean that when I run the code it extract the specific data but I don't know how to add that data in front of it's value for e.g `column D`.

Code of scrapping Web :

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
   Sub extt()

   Dim IE As Object, obj As Object
   Dim itm As IHTMLElement
   Dim htmlcurrentDoc As IHTMLElement
   Dim elemCollection As Object
   Dim c As Long, d As Long, i As Long, x As Long, f As Variant
   Dim tags As Object
   Dim oHtml  As HTMLDocument
   Dim lastRow As Variant
   Dim ModNum As Variant
   Dim doc As Object
   Dim tagx As Object
   Dim tRow As Object, tCel As Object
   Dim a As Object
   Dim l As Object
   Dim y As Long, z As Long, ws As Excel.Worksheet
   
                   'add the microsoft Internet Controls

   Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

   Workbooks("firsttry").Sheets("Feuil1").Activate 'Activate sheets("Feuil1")

   lastRow = Worksheets("Feuil2").Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).row
       With IE
         d = 0
         For Each f In Sheets("Feuil2").Range("C2:C" & lastRow).Value
         ModNum = f
         d = d + 1
   IE.Visible = True

       .Visible = True
       .navigate "http://This an internal WebSite /consultation/preSearchMOD.do?clearBackList=true&CMH_NO_STORING_fromMenu=true"
 While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
              'we ensure that the web Page is loaded completely


   Set itm = IE.document.getElementsByName("searchById")(0)
     If Not itm Is Nothing Then itm.Value = ModNum
      Set doc = IE.document
          Set tags = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
             For Each tagx In tags
                If tagx.src = "http://ithis an internal WebSite/cmh/cmh/image/button_search.gif" Then  
              ' Search button ==>This Part reach That source of search button and click on it
               tagx.Click
            End If
           Next

    Call WaitIE(IE, 1000)
    For Each l In doc.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If l.href = "http://This an internal WebSite/cmh/consultation/preViewMODScheduling.do?fromSelect=true" Then  
                ' This Part search for the Href and click on it to changePage

   l.Click
   End If
   Next
   'Debug.Print elemCollection.Length
   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
   Workbooks("firsttry").Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A1:AK500").ClearContents 
    'Clear the Content of ActiveWorkbook  (A1:AK500)


  x = 2
  c = 1
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
  On Error Resume Next
  While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
     Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
     oHtml.body.innerHTML = IE.document.body.innerHTML
      Set elemCollection = oHtml.getElementsByTagName("table")(62)      
                ' Search for Table 62 and Extract it into Sheet 1
       For Each tRow In elemCollection.Rows
       For Each tCel In tRow.Cells
       Cells(x, c) = tCel.innerText
       c = c + 1
       Next tCel
      c = 1
      x = x + 1
      Next tRow
      Next f
  End With
  Set IE = Nothing
 MsgBox "Done"
 End Sub

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------

 Sub WaitIE(IE As Object, Optional time As Long = 250)
 Dim i As Long
 Do
       Sleep time
       Debug.Print CStr(i) & vbTab & "Ready: " & CStr(IE.readyState = 4) & _
            vbCrLf & vbTab & "Busy: " & CStr(IE.Busy)
 i = i + 1
 Loop Until IE.readyState = 4 And Not IE.Busy
 End Sub
```

As you Can see in this code I got this Variable `ModNum` which allows me to use values that are located in this Table column C and extract the Data from our Internal Website and print it in front of it and then pass on to the next Value to make the search

[image]

To resume :after extracting the Data from web site I want to put that data in front of each Value in that Table in the  `column D`

Anyone can light me with this ?

Best regards

Polos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to search for that Value and offset to the right until reaching colum 4 
so try this maybe it could Help

```
 Sub test()
 Dim tex As String
 Dim r As Range

   tex = "FullTRS official (TCM) "

 Set r = Cells.Find(What:=tex, After:=Cells(1), LookAt:=xlPart)
 r.Select
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Copy
  'type your deserved Task under this
  End Sub
```

this Code helps you to select your desired Text then if copy the value in front of it with `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Copy`

Comment: your code worked for me but how can I transfert that Data infront of  each cell , I updated My answer

Comment: Thank you I used this                                                                          
                                                                                                            
 'l2 = Range("A1:A20").Find(tex, lookat:=xlWhole).row
If Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("D" & l2).Value <> "" Then
Worksheets("Feuil2").Range("D" & d).Value = Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("D" & l2).Value'

Comment: Glad that it helped you

Answer (score 1):

I created This But is there any better solution  :

Infront of each Line I added the name of Data That I want to add like this :

[image]

and I created this code to compare if the `FULLTRS official(TCM)` exists in sheet1 `Range("A2:A")or Cells(i, 1)` then offset to colum 4 and copy it

```
For i = 1 To 100
If Sheets("Feuil2").Range("E3").Value = "FullTRS official (TCM) " Then
If Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(i, 1) Like Sheets("Feuil2").Range("E3").Value Then
tex = "FullTRS official (TCM) "
 Set r = Cells.Find(What:=tex, After:=Cells(1), LookAt:=xlPart)
 r.Select
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Feuil2").Cells(f, 3).Select
 ActiveCell.Paste

End If
End If
Next
Next f
```

--------Thanks to @Fayrouzouerghui

but the problem of this solution that it doesn't copy the line i and column 4  for e.G if the word `FULLTRS official(TCM)` in line 4 then it goes to column 4 and line 4 and copy data then Paste it in the Other Page infront of the Value

this Part of code does'nt work

```
     Selection.Copy
     Sheets("Feuil2").Cells(f, 3).Select
     ActiveCell.Paste
```

So I was wondering if someone can help